# How to use NICEDIT with jquery easyui

Tags: nicedit, jquery-easyui

Anyone know how to work with jquery and niceedit easyui
Not retrieve the text from the database

```
    <div id="sample">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../inc/js/nicEdit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor({
        iconsPath:'../inc/js/nicEditorIcons.gif',
        uploadURI : 'UploadArquivo.php', 
    }).panelInstance('textareaId');
});

</script>
<?       
<div class="fitem">
    <textarea  id="textareaId" name="texto" style="width: 650px; height: 300px;"></textarea>
</div>
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and your question unclear. Please correct your post.

Comment: I try to implement nicedit with easyui, but not work, I have searched in google and not found any reference

Comment: what do you mean with `<?` code under `</script>` and before `<div class="fitem">`?
this is a the problem, it's suppose to place under the `</div>`